# Why can't node handle this regex but python can?

Tags: python, regex, node.js

I have a large text file that I am extracting URLs from. If I run:

```
import re

with open ('file.in', 'r') as fh:
   for match in re.findall(r'http://matchthis\.com', fh.read()):
      print match
```

it runs in a second or so user time and gets the URLs I was wanting, but if I run either of these:

```
var regex = /http:\/\/matchthis\.com/g;
fs.readFile('file.in', 'ascii', function(err, data) {
   while(match = regex.exec(data))
      console.log(match);
});
```

OR

```
fs.readFile('file.in', 'ascii', function(err, data) {
   var matches = data.match(/http:\/\/matchthis\.com/g);
   for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
      console.log(matches[i]);
   }
});
```

I get:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

What is happening with the `node.js` regex engine? Is there any way I can modify things such that they work in `node`?

**EDIT:** The error appears to be `fs` centric as this also produces the error:

```
fs.readFile('file.in', 'ascii', function(err, data) {

});
```

`file.in` is around 800MB.

Comment: What's in `file.in`? Can you make a reproducible example? Also, `http://matchthis.com` isn't escaped properly. You need to escape the period.

Comment: @Blender fixed the `\.` I missed it as I typed out the question. `file.in` is 1400000 lines of ascii text containing URLs in amongst various text snippets.

Comment: @Blender Shouldn't the dot be fixed in Python as well?

Comment: The escaping of `.` doesn't make a difference to the result I outlined above, I still get out of memory error in `node` but not `python`.

Comment: I'm no python expert, but suspect the critical difference is that the for loop and `re.findall` can process the file as it's read, so there's very little memory in use at any point in time, whereas `readFile` tries to read the entire file into memory before doing the regexp search?  Do you have enough memory to do that?  May be worth checking `fs.readFile` docs.

Comment: My first question is, does it work without the regex? Does `fs.readFile('file.in', 'ascii', function(err, data) { });` throw anything? How large is the file in MB? You may need to process it as a stream with `fs.createReadStream()`

Comment: @TonyD: But OP is calling `fh.read()`, which reads the entire file into memory.

Comment: @loganfsmyth ahh good one. It is in fact the fs.readFile throwing the out of memory error. An empty body in the callback results in the same behaviour.

Comment: `fs.readFile` uses `fs.fstat` to get the file size, and then does a read with this full size buffer. Using `fs.read` with a smaller buffer, or a `ReadStream` should get around the memory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should process the file line by line using the streaming file interface. Something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var byline = require('byline');

var input = fs.createReadStream('tmp.txt');
var lines = input.pipe(byline.createStream());

lines.on('readable', function(){
    var line = lines.read().toString('ascii');

    var matches = line.match(/http:\/\/matchthis\.com/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
        console.log(matches[i]);
    }
});
```

In this example, I'm using the `byline` module to split the stream into lines so that you won't miss matches by getting partial chunks of lines per `.read()` call.

To elaborate more, what you were doing is allocating ~800MB of RAM as a Buffer (outside of V8's heap) and then converting that to an ASCII string (and thus transferring it into V8's heap), which will take at least 800MB and likely more depending on V8's internal optimizations. I believe V8 stores strings as UCS2 or UTF16, which means each character will be 2 bytes (given ASCII input) so your string would really be about 1600MB.

Node's max allocated heap space is 1.4GB, so by trying to create such a large string, you cause V8 to throw an exception.

Python does not have this problem because it does not have a maximum heap size and will chew through all of your RAM. As others have pointed out, you should also avoid `fh.read()` in Python since that will copy all the file data into RAM as a string instead of streaming it line by line with an iterator.

Comment: This does indeed solve the error but does take some 10-15 seconds longer than the python script for reasons outlined above.

Comment: @hpaulj 2 seconds user vs 15 seconds user for `node` and `byline`. `node` doesn't experience the 800MB jump in memory being  used though.

Answer (score 1):

Given that both programs are trying to read the entire 1400000 file into memory, I'd suggest it would be a difference between how Node and Python handle large strings. Try doing a line by line search and the problem should disappear.

For example, in Python you can do this:

```
import re
with open ('file.in', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for match in re.findall(r'http://matchthis\.com', line):
            print match
```